# How a get full path of hidden files?

Tags: batch-file

> I want get a full paths of files, including hidden files and folders with specific extensions in one folder and print this path. How I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can use:

```
for /f "delims=" %%p in ('dir /B /S /A *.ext') do echo %%p
```

> A option /A includes a hidden files.

Comment: Thanks, I can include others extensions in this command, like ('dir /B /S /A *.ext1 *.ext2 *.ext3 ...')